# Invoke, pylint and codesytle

Tags: python, pytest, invoke, lint, pycodestyle

I am learning the invoke library to make my life a bit easier.

I have three tasks.

- run tests
- run lint
- run codestyle

And now I thought I could make a task that calls them all.

```
@task(pre=[tests, lint, codestyle])
def run_all(c):
    pass
```

All my tasks are working fine by themselves. But depending on the order in the pre-task list some of the tasks will not run. I know that lint and codestyle are similar, but this is just for learning purposes. If I put lint first, then none of the other tasks will run when I invoke run-all.

I've also tried using `post=[lint]`, alas, I'm still not able to execute all of the tasks with my super-task.

My question is:
Is it not possible to run pycodestyle and pylint in consecutive order using invoke task?